# Вызов одной функции за другой и вывод результата их общей работы

Tags: python, функции, python-3.x

У меня 2 коротких вопроса:

1. Как подключить одну функцию к другой (чтоб результат первой функции передался во вторую)?
2. Как правильно вывести общий результат работы этих двух функций?

До комментария

```
#!!!!----->
```

код работает. Не могу правильно состыковать то, что идет ниже этого самого комментария.

```
    import requests
    from lxml.html import fromstring

    def prepare(url): #Готовим страницу к парсингу
        url = requests.get(url)

        tree = fromstring(url.text)
        tree.make_links_absolute(url.url)
        return tree

    def cinemas_info(url): 
        def basic_cinemas_info(url): 
        '''Получаем Город, Название и Детальную_ссылку'''

            prepare(url)
            tree = prepare(url)

            for city in tree.xpath(".//div[@class='city-caption']"):
                for cinema in city.xpath("following-sibling::*[1]/li/a"):
                    city1 = city.xpath("text()")[0]
                    name1 = cinema.xpath("text()")[0]
                    detailed_url = cinema.xpath("@href")[0]
                    return city1, name1, detailed_url

    #!!!!-----> Не могу правильно подцепить нижнюю часть кода к верхней <------!!!!!

        def detailed_cinemas_info():
        '''из basic_cinemas_info нужно получить "detailed_url" для дополучения нужной информации (Улицы, Телефона, Сайта)'''

            detailed_url = basic_cinemas_info(url)[2]
            #ВОПРОС: Как правильно получить detailed_url из def basic_cinemas_info(url)?

            prepare(detailed_url)
            tree = prepare(url)

            for street in tree.xpath(".//div[@class='address']"):
                street1 = street.xpath("text()")[0]
                for phone in tree.xpath(".//div[@class='phone']"):
                    phone1 = phone.xpath("text()")[0]
                    for website in tree.xpath(".//div[@class='website']/a"):
                        website1 = website.xpath("@href")[0]
                        return street1, phone1, website1

        print (city1,name1,street1,phone1,website1)
        '''итог работы двух функций объединяем и выводим'''
        #ВОПРОС: Как правильно вывести объединенный результат функций basic_cinemas_info и detailed_cinemas_info?

    cinemas_info('http://vkino.com.ua/cinema/#!=')
```

Принцип парсинга "один-к многим", т.е. на одной странице есть список всех кинотеатров с базовой инфой и дальше обращаемся к детальной странице каждого кинотеатра для получения доп инфы. Результат работы двух функций объединяем и выводим.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так:

```
import requests
from lxml.html import fromstring


class cinemas_info():
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.basic_cinemas_info(url)

    def prepare(self, url): #Готовим страницу к парсингу
        url = requests.get(url)
        tree = fromstring(url.text)
        tree.make_links_absolute(url.url)
        return tree

    def basic_cinemas_info(self, url): 
        '''Получаем Город, Название и Детальную_ссылку'''

        tree = self.prepare(url)
        for city in tree.xpath(".//div[@class='city-caption']"):
            for cinema in city.xpath("following-sibling::*[1]/li/a"):
                city1 = city.xpath("text()")[0]
                name1 = cinema.xpath("text()")[0]
                detailed_url = cinema.xpath("@href")[0]
                print city1.strip(), name1.strip(), ':'
                self.detailed_cinemas_info(detailed_url)

    def detailed_cinemas_info(self, url):
        '''из basic_cinemas_info нужно получить "detailed_url" для дополучения нужной информации (Улицы, Телефона, Сайта)'''

        tree = self.prepare(url)
        for street in tree.xpath(".//div[@class='address']"):
            street1 = street.xpath("text()")[0]
            for phone in tree.xpath(".//div[@class='phone']"):
                phone1 = phone.xpath("text()")[0]
                for website in tree.xpath(".//div[@class='website']/a"):
                    website1 = website.xpath("@href")[0]
                    print '\t', street1.strip(), phone1.strip(), website1.strip()

cinemas_info('http://vkino.com.ua/cinema/#!=')
```